# Save row_slice information in workbook xlrd python

Tags: python, excel, pydev, xlrd, xlwt

I am trying to extract the header row (the first row) from multiple files, each of which has multiple sheets. The output of each sheet should be saved and appened in a new master file that contains all the headers from each sheet and each file.

The easiest way I have found is to use the command row_slice. However, the output from the file is a list of Cell objects and I cannot seem to access their indices.

I am looking for a way to save the data extracted into a new workbook.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook,cellname
book = open_workbook('E:\Files_combine\MOU worksheets 2012\Walmart-GE_MOU 2012-209_worksheet_v03.xls')
last_index = len(book.sheet_names()) 
for sheet_index in range(last_index):
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(sheet_index)
print sheet.name
print sheet.row_slice(0,1)
```

I cannot get the output and store it as an input to a new file. Also, any ideas on how to automate this process for 100+ files will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the output in a csv file and you can use the os.listdir and a for loop to loop over all the file names

```
import csv
import os

from xlrd import open_workbook, cellname

EXCEL_DIR = 'E:\Files_combine\MOU worksheets 2012'
with open("headers.csv", 'w') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for file_name in os.listdir(EXCEL_DIR):
        if file_name.endswith("xls"):
            book = open_workbook(os.path.join(EXCEL_DIR, file_name))
            for index, name in enumerate(book.sheet_names()):
                sheet = book.sheet_by_index(index)
                #the write row method takes a sequence
                #I assume that row_slice returns a list or a tuple
                writer.writerow(sheet.row_slice(0,1))
```